# Haskell: Show for data with types like :: * -> *

Tags: haskell, types, show

i have a problem to implement a show instance for a datatype with types

here is the code:

```
data RMcom = LOAD Int | STORE Int | CLOAD Integer | CADD Integer | 
             CSUB Integer | CMULT Integer | CDIV Integer | ADD Int | 
             SUB Int | MULT Int | DIV Int | GOTO Integer | JZERO Integer | 
             END deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

type RMprog = Integer -> RMcom

type Register = Int -> Integer

data RMstate = State {progr :: RMprog, pc :: Integer, reg :: Register, maxReg :: Int}
```

Its a simulation for a Registermachine

So now i want to make a instance for Show RMstate on my own.

Normaly i would do it like this

```
instance Show RMstate where
   show(State progr pc reg maxReg) = show(progr)++show(pc)++show(reg)++show(maxReg)
```

But the compiler wants to have a instance for Show RMprog and Register, but how
can i make a instance for types?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

The `RMProg` and `Register` types are functions.  Functions cannot be shown in any interesting way in general.  You can get something by importing `Text.Show.Functions`, but it's probably not what you want.

I suggest you use `newtype` for those two types and write your own `Show` instances that does something better.

E.g.

```
newtype Register = Register (Int -> Integer)
instance Show Register where
    show (Register f) = "Registers:" ++ show [(i, f i) | i <- [0..15] ]
```

Comment: Any possibilities to get it working without additional imports , just in the show function?

Comment: Yes, you can write your own instance for `Show (a -> b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do something like

```
instance Show (x -> y) where
  show _ = "<function>"
```

Then the code will *work*... It won't show you much of any interest, but it will *work*.

(This is basically what importing `Text.Show.Functions` does.)

Personally I'd go for the suggestion from augustss, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
```

I've taken the liberty of adding `maxProg :: Integer` so we know where to stop the `RMprog`.

```
data RMstate = State {progr :: RMprog, pc :: Integer, reg :: Register, 
                      maxReg :: Int, maxProg::Integer}
```

First, let's make a function that shows functions like `RMprog` and `Register` a line at a time, so that for example,

```
ghci> putStrLn $ showIndexed (+100) 1
1       101
```

like this:

```
showIndexed :: (Show i, Show v) => (i -> v) -> i -> String
showIndexed f i = show i ++ '\t':show (f i)
```

Now we can show the `RMstate`, by gluing together lines of output:

```
instance Show RMstate where 
   show s = unlines $ 
               ["","Program:"] 
               ++ [showIndexed (progr s) i | i <- [0..maxProg s]]
               ++ ["","PC:\t"++show (pc s),"","Registers:"]
               ++ [showIndexed (reg s) i | i <- [0..maxReg s]]


example = State {progr=p, pc=3, reg=r, maxReg=15, maxProg=10} where        
  p = fromJust.flip lookup (zip [0..] [LOAD 3, STORE 2, CLOAD 1, 
                                          CADD 12, CSUB 4, CMULT 5, 
                                          CDIV 2, ADD 123, SUB 10, 
                                          MULT 5, DIV 2, GOTO 6, 
                                          JZERO 4, END])

  r = fromJust . flip lookup (zip [0..] [3,4,3,5,6,5,2,5,7,2,4,5,672,5,56,3])
```

which looks like:

```
ghci> print example

Program:
0       LOAD 3
1       STORE 2
2       CLOAD 1
3       CADD 12
4       CSUB 4
5       CMULT 5
6       CDIV 2
7       ADD 123
8       SUB 10
9       MULT 5
10      DIV 2

PC:       3

Registers:
0       3
1       4
2       3
3       5
4       6
5       5
6       2
7       5
8       7
9       2
10      4
11      5
12      672
13      5
14      56
15      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
instance Show RMstate where
show (State  prog i reg k) =
   "\n"++"naechster Befehl: "++(show $ prog i)++"\n"++"Registerbelegungen: \n"++
   (concat [ (show i)++": "++(show $ reg i)++"\n" | i <- [0..k]])
```